# Opencart payment required fields processing issue

Tags: opencart, authorize.net

Can someone please tell me where the validation happens for Opencart authorizenet_aim? It appears to be checking cc_number and expiration but I can't find it.

I have added the error checking in `payment/authorizenet_aim.php` using the `$json['error']` array but still have the `alert()` popping up which says, `[object Object]`.

controller/payment/authorizenet_aim.php:

```
public function send() {
  $json = array();
  $data = array();

  $this->language->load('payment/authorizenet_aim');

  if(isset($this->request->post['cc_owner']) && '' == $this->request-post['cc_owner']) {
    $json['error']['cc_owner'] = $this->language->get('error_cc_owner');
  } else {
      $json['error']['cc_owner'] = '';
  }

  if(isset($this->request->post['cc_number']) && '' == $this->request->post['cc_number']) {
    $json['error']['cc_number'] = $this->language->get('error_cc_number');
  } else {
      $json['error']['cc_number'] = '';
  }

  if(isset($this->request->post['cc_cvv2']) && '' == $this->request->post['cc_cvv2']) {
    $json['error']['cc_cvv2'] = $this->language->get('error_cc_cvv2');
  } else {
    $json['error']['cc_cvv2'] = '';
  }

  if(!isset($json['error']['cc_owner']) && !isset($json['error']['cc_number']) && !isset($json['error']['cc_cvv2'])) {
    ...//curl
  }

  $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

template/payment/authorizenet_aim.tpl

```
<script>
  $('#button-confirm').bind('click', function() {
    ...
    success: function() {
      if(json['error']) {
        if(json['error']['cc_owner']) {
          $('input[name=cc_owner]').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['cc_owner']);
        ...
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After earning a tumbleweed badge, I thought I better redeem myself and figure this out. Here are the basics:

catalog/controller/payment/authorizenet_aim.php/send:

```
$json = array();                                                                                                                    

$this->language->load('payment/authorizenet_aim');                                                                                  

if(!isset($this->request->post['cc_owner']) || '' == $this->request->post['cc_owner']) {                                            
  $json['error']['cc_owner'] = $this->language->get('error_cc_owner');                                                              
}                                                                                                                                   

if(!isset($this->request->post['cc_number']) || '' == $this->request->post['cc_number']) {                                          
  $json['error']['cc_number'] = $this->language->get('error_cc_number');                                                            
}                                                                                                                                   

if(!isset($this->request->post['cc_cvv2']) || '' == $this->request->post['cc_cvv2']) {                                              
  $json['error']['cc_cvv2'] = $this->language->get('error_cc_cvv2');                                                                
}
...
if(!isset($json['error']['cc_owner']) && !isset($json['error']['cc_number']) && !isset($json['error']['cc_cvv2'])) {

  $curl = curl_init($url);
  ...
  curl_close($curl);
}

$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
```

catalog/view/theme/mytheme/template/payment/authorizenet_aim.tpl:

```
$('#button-confirm').bind('click', function() {

  $('span.error').remove();

  $.ajax({

    ...

    success: function() {
      if (json['error']) {

        if(json['error']['cc_owner'] || json['error']['cc_number'] || json['error']['cc_cvv2']) {

          var error_msg = "You have missed some required fields:\n";

          if (json['error']['cc_owner']) {
            $('input[name=cc_owner]').after('<span class="error" style="display:inline-table;margin-left:12px;font-size:small;">' + json['error']['cc_owner']);
            error_msg += "- " + json['error']['cc_owner'] + "\n";
          }

          if (json['error']['cc_number']) {
            $('input[name=cc_number]').after('<span class="error" style="display:inline-table;margin-left:12px;font-size:small;">' + json['error']['cc_number']);
            error_msg += "- " + json['error']['cc_number'] + "\n";
          }

          if (json['error']['cc_cvv2']) {
            $('input[name=cc_cvv2]').after('<span class="error" style="display:inline-table;margin-left:12px;font-size:small;">' + json['error']['cc_cvv2']);
            error_msg += "- " + json['error']['cc_cvv2'] + "\n";
          }

          alert(error_msg);
        } else {
            alert(json['error']);
        }
    }
    ...
```

I'm working on additional Luhn, etc., but this is a good start.